# GSON: De-serialising a generic object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am attempting to de-serialise some JSON from Wikipedia using the GSON library. Typically, I would create each object in Java as they are in JSON, as example:

```
{
    query: {
        pages: {
            page: {
                pageid: 168079,
                ns: 0,
                title: "2010 FIFA World Cup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to de-serialise using the following Java code:

```
class PageIdResponseGson
{
    private QueryResults query;

    public static class QueryResults
    {
        private PageResults pages;

        public PageResults getPages() {
            return pages;
        }
    }

    public static class PageResults
    {
        private PageResult page;

        public PageResult getPage() {
            return page;
        }
    }

    public static class PageResult
    {
        private int pageid;
        private int ns;
        private String title;

        public int getNs() {
            return ns;
        }

        public int getPageid() {
            return pageid;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public QueryResults getQuery() {
        return query;
    }
}
```

However the Wikipedia JSON uses the page-id as the object name, which means I can't take this approach.

```
{
    query: {
        pages: {
            168079: {
                pageid: 168079,
                ns: 0,
                title: "2010 FIFA World Cup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can use some kind of generic wrapper to handle these dynamic object names?

Comment: PS: I'd rather not use JSONObject etc; if possible keep to GSON.

Answer (score 1):

You have several alternatives here:

1. You use Hashmaps-->Anything can be a key in a hashmap and GSON will do just fine.
2. You implement your own TypeAdapter and TypeAdapterFactory to handle such cases and when you meet a field that is a number that does not exists in your target class then you know you have your pageId and it should be remapped on your PageResults.page member.